# How do I get a lookup column to filter in 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, column, filter

I have data in page view that places the information for "project" in a lookup column.  When I try to filter this column I get the error "this column cannot be filtered."  How to I get this column to filter?  The other columns filter with no issue.  This is the only lookup column.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by removing the "multiple values" check! Who knew?

Comment: While not a long winded answer, it does provide a solution/answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

their is no OOTB way to filter the LookUp. Their are couple of options you can try.

- [Use SharePoint designer with a text column to get this](http://sprider.org/2012/05/10/how-to-filter-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/)
- [Applying Filters to Lookup Fields with the SharePoint 2013 REST API](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Applying-Filters-to-Lookup-Fields-with-the-SP2013-REST-API)
- [their is codePlex solution for this](http://sp2013filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I fixed it by removing the "multiple values" check!  Who knew?